# Splunk Coalesce Function

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Hello I'm trying to utilize the coalesce eval function within Splunk. However, the eval function doesn't like fields that have a space in them.

In the past I've gotten around this by utilizing the rename function to change the field with a space in it to a field name without a space. However, that is not working this time for some reason.

Is there alternatives to using fields with spaces in eval statements besides rename trick?

example

```
base search
|eval test=coalesce(field1,field2)
| rename "space field 1" AS field1, "space field 2" AS field2
| table field1 field2 test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPL you shared shows the `rename` *after* you attempt to `coalesce()`:

```
base search
| eval test=coalesce(field1,field2)
| rename "space field 1" AS field1, "space field 2" AS field2
| table field1 field2 test
```

Pretty sure what you want is this:

```
base search
| rename "space field 1" AS field1, "space field 2" AS field2
| eval test=coalesce(field1,field2)
| table field1 field2 test
```

Comment: You are correct, order of execution is why my orginal query didn't work. I knew I was missing something as I had this working before forgot order matters.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around text in the `eval` command to designate the text as a field name.  Double quotes around the text make it a string constant.

```
base search
| eval test=coalesce('space field 1','space field 2')
| table "space field 1" "space field 2" test
```

Notice how the `table` command does not use this convention.  All arguments to `table` are treated as field names.

Comment: I havne't check back but came to this result as well. However, Warren is correct as well, both yeild the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out.You have to use single quotes around fields with spaces in them.

Remember that coalesce uses these fields in order provided when filling in a non-NULL value. So keep that in mind when using this function as well!

Working example:

```
base search
| eval test=coalesce('space field 1','space field 2')
| rename "space field 1" AS field1, "space field 2" AS field2
| table field1 field2 test
```

Comment: Thanks to both Warren and RichG both are correct and will yield the same results!